# How to check if there is problem with wireless part of 2.4G wireless keyboard + mouse set with USB receivier

Tags: keyboard, wireless-networking, mouse

Is there any way to check if the trouble with keyboard and/or mouse becoming unresponsive, where keyboard and mouse are from 2.4G wireless optical mouse & standard keyboard set, is caused by some interference with wireless signal, problem with USB receiver, or problem with operating system (with software)?

**Hardware in question:** [Media-Tech "Melville" (MT1413US)](http://www.media-tech.pl/page.php?do=details&lang=pl&pid=1773&kid=20) 2.4G wireless optical mouse & standard keyboard set,

**Software in question:** GNU/Linux with X-Window System.

---

***Status for 29-07-2009:***

Mouse from the set works correctly and without trouble; keyboard stopped working at all (even very close to the 2.4GHz RF receivier).  Swapping AA battery for new one (even though it should still have juice) didn't help.  It might be software issue: `lsusb -v` lists "Keyboard" HID device.

Fortunately I still have old wired PS/2 keyboard this one was to be replacement for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For troubleshooting these types of problems I tend to do three things:

- Plug a USB wired keyboard and mouse into the computer to see if there is a problem with the operating system.  Unless you installed special drivers for your keyboard + mouse wireless then this will confirm that your OS isn't going nuts.  Try to use the computer with a wired keyboard/mouse for a while because your issues seem to be intermittent.   Given that it is X.org, I don't think this is the case.
- Move the receiver closer to the keyboard and mouse.  Like, much MUCH closer.  Think inches.  I know it is not really useful to have a wireless mouse and keyboard when the receiver has a big USB cable sticking out of it.  This step is testing that the wireless works at all.  If there are still issues with the receiver this close, your hardware is broken, or there is interference.
- Test for interference with a spectrum analyzer.  You can buy one of [these](http://www.thinkgeek.com/interests/techies/80ce/), which works remarkably well for a 2.4GHz region.  I used one once to find out that whenever my neighbor was microwaving something I couldn't get any wifi.  Frustrating.

If all else fails, it's probably just cheaper to buy a new setup.  You can usually get the performance you are looking for with a bluetooth keyboard+mouse nowadays.

Comment: Inches. Check. Working. Moved receiver from the back of the case with a cable extension somewhere at the front of my desk, working at 2m range. Thank you!

Comment: wow my mouse connected finally! move your mouse to basically touching the usb receiver when pairing it. Upvote @jamuraa now!

Answer (score 1):

How far is the reciever from the keyboard and mouse? Also, is the reciever under a desk or behind anything metal?  I had a wireless set that had trouble because computer was on the floor and wireless receiver was on top of machine.  It was only a couple feet from the set. I had a metal desk though, so mouse was jumpy and keyboard sluggish at times.  I moved the reciever on top of desk and all my troubles went away.

EDIT:

You might want to get a USB extender cable to get the reciever to a better location.

Comment: Receiver is small USB dongle, which is unfortunately put in USB port at the back of computer (because it is fairly old computer without USB ports in the front).  The desk is small wooden computer desk; the trouble might be with metal rails for keyboard tray.